# How to model a soft enum using a backing table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, relationship

I have an existing pair of tables, unfortunately I can't change anything about them since they come from a different application and at least for the forseeable future that application still has to work on the database as well.

I have two tables:
`partner`:

| id | status | salutation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1001 | 0 |

and `code`:

| id | code | set | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 1 | 1 | "regular" |
| 22 | 2 | 1 | "vip" |
| 23 | 1001 | 1 | "repeated" |
| 24 | 0 | 2 | "" |
| 25 | 1 | 2 | "Madam" |
| 26 | 2 | 2 | "Sir" |

Where a `code.set` of `1` corresponds to an entry for `partner.status`
and a `code.set` of `2` signals an entry for `partner.salutation`

I'm trying to model the relations but could not find out how to limit a specific relation to only a subset of the other table:
`Entity/Partner.php`

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PartnerRepository::class)]
class Partner {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "status", referencedColumnName: "code")]
    private ?Code $status = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "salutation", referencedColumnName: "code")]
    private ?Code $salutation = null;
}
```

This now fetches the wrong `label`s for a status of `1` because of course the same value is used for both `status = "regular"` and `salutation = "Madam"`

Ideally I'd like to write something like

```php
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(filter: "set = 1")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "status", referencedColumnName: "code")]
    private ?Code $status = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(filter: "set = 2")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "salutation", referencedColumnName: "code")]
    private ?Code $salutation = null;
```

or maybe add a `#[Filter]` attribute, but I could not figure out the right syntax/ place to apply the `Filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not quite the solution I was looking for I'll probably end up using inheritance for the different code sets:

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\CodeRepository;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PartnerRepository::class)]
class Partner {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "status", referencedColumnName: "code")]
    private ?StatusCode $status = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "salutation", referencedColumnName: "code")]
    private ?SalutationCode $salutation = null;
}

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CodeRepository::class)]
#[ORM\InheritanceType('SINGLE_TABLE')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'set', type: 'bigint')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([1 => StatusCode::class, 2 => SalutationCode::class])]
class Code {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Partner::class)]
    private ?Partner $code = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $label = null;
}
#[ORM\Entity]
class StatusCode extends Code {}
#[ORM\Entity]
class SalutationCode extends Code {}
```